# UICollectionView does not recognise tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView` inside `ViewController` and it doesn't perform segue to the second `ViewController`

My code is below:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "showFood" else { return }
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? FoodViewController else { return }
    destination.food = sender as? Food
}

extension AllFoodViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFood", sender: food[indexPath.row])
}
```

Also, I have this function in ViewDidLoad

```
    private func configureCollectionView() {
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

[App design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I40a.png)

[Segue connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvKIs.png)

Comment: I'm assuming you called configureCollectionView() on viewDidLoad() of that particular view controller? Assuming you did, it might be helpful to change your guard statements to "if let" statements, so you can add some debug prints in your code. That way you can see if you're even getting past those parts of the code.

Comment: Yes, I called function on that ViewController

Comment: Then I would take a look to make sure that your segue is properly configured (make sure to hit 'return' after typing the identifier in.. it's tripped me up in the past not having done that!). From what you've posted, the code looks like it should fire, but you're going to miss some critical debugging steps if you're just calling "return" on those guard statements.

Comment: I made breakpoint on segue and it does not work,  so the app does not recognise my taps. I also tried on iPhone and had the same result

Comment: Show the segue connection in the design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Call the function which configures the collection view methods in `viewDidLoad()`

2- Make sure that you've connected it like the image below:

[image]

3- Don't forget to write the segue identifier in the view controller like the image below:
[image]

4- Make sure that user interaction is enabled
[image]

Comment: try not to use guard and use this directly: let destination = segue.destination as? FoodViewController and tell me what happened

Comment: tried not to use guard and I don't get any response from tap
I have configureCollectionView() in my ViewDidLoad

Comment: can you edit the post and show me the design?

Comment: make sure that food you are using is an array and the second one is a variable as you are using two variables under the same "food"

Comment: Updated my post with a link to app design.
Yes they are both variable

Comment: Show the segue connection in the design

Comment: Updated with segue connection screenshot

Comment: I know that this may not be the reason but can you make it push instead of show details ?

Comment: another question, did you set the number of items in the collection view?

Comment: Tried to make segue as a push but no result. In number of sections I return array count

Comment: change it to number of row not number of sections and it may work

Comment: I can not change numberOfItemsInSection. Can you help me please due to my inexperience

Comment: Sure, can I get your email please?

Comment: Check your email

Comment: I will check it

Comment: are you creating the app for a watch not a mobile?

Comment: I am learning swift and making apps to understand it

Comment: Still no result, it didn’t work with interaction and without it

Comment: Enable user interaction for the cell and the collection view, It works with me already

Comment: Made it but still no results, can you send your version of app please?